# Counting of natural number

Tags: coq

I have natural number list. Want to count number(a) in the list while a is not zero. I want to write a lambda that counts a in the list and gives some natural number at the output.Secondly if I have information that greatest element in the list is zero then how to modify lambda.

```
  a<>0 ->
 count (S a)(b::l)<= S n.
```

`

Comment: Could you reformulate your question? For example, could give more examples of the relation.